# Mutli Application Calling Model From Shared Site In Single Installation Codeigniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

How to call models from other multi application site in single installation codeigniter 4 ?

The folder structure look like this :

```
- WebsiteFolder
  -- Site1
     --- app
     --- public
     --- tests
     --- writeable
     (.env, spark and other file)
  -- Site2
     --- app
     --- public
     --- tests
     --- writeable
     (.env, spark and other file)
  -- system
```

This is my example code :

**In Site1**

---

**Constants.php**
I have define a root directory to targeted the site2.

```
define('ROOTSOURCE', dirname(__DIR__,3) . '\site2');
```

This return :

*E:\Project\website\site2*

**Autoload.php**

I have setup PSR4.

```
 public $psr4 = [
        APP_NAMESPACE => APPPATH, // For custom app namespace
        'Config'      => APPPATH . 'Config',        
        'Source\Models' => ROOTSOURCE . '/app/Models/'
    ];
```

Then I Run SPARK COMMAND :

```
php spark namespaces
```

And return

```
+---------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
| Namespace     | Path                                                                                    | Found? |
+---------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
| CodeIgniter   | E:\Project\DennisLiu\website\system                                         | Yes    |
| App           | E:\Project\DennisLiu\website\site1\app        | Yes    |
| Config        | E:\Project\DennisLiu\website\site1\app\Config | Yes    |
| Source\Models | E:\Project\DennisLiu\website\site2\app\Models           | Yes    |
+---------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
```

Then NameSpace **Source\Models** is Found. So far everything is okay.

Controller => **Home.php**

```
namespace App\Controllers;
use Source\Models;


class Home extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {                
        
        $setting = new \Source\Models\Setting();                                                    

        return view('welcome_message');
        
    }
```

When I run the controller I got :

> **Class "Source\Models\Setting" not found**

Next,

**In Site2**

I have model **"Setting"** in Site2 Model Folder.

**For Note :**

Everything In Site 2 Is running properly.

My question is for the error I got "Class **"Source\Models\Setting" not found"** What is the proper setting to call the site 2 model in single application installation codeigniter 4 ?.

**For Note :**
This is single installation codeigniter 4 for two website. And I shared the system folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. This is the correct way to do this.

*Folder Structure*

```
- WebsiteFolder
  -- Site1
     --- app
     --- public
     --- tests
     --- writeable
     (.env, spark and other file)
  -- Site2
     --- app
     --- public
     --- tests
     --- writeable
     (.env, spark and other file)
  -- shared/Models
     (DBSetting.php)
  -- system
```

**Controller - Home.php**

```
namespace App\Controllers;
use shared\Models\DBSetting;



class Home extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {                
        
        $db = new \shared\Models\DBSetting();                

        return view('welcome_message');
        
    }
}
```

**Autoload.php**

```
 public $psr4 = [
        APP_NAMESPACE   => APPPATH, // For custom app namespace
        'Config'        => APPPATH . 'Config',               
        'shared\Models' => ROOTSOURCE . '/shared/Models'        
    ];
```

**Constants.php**

```
define('ROOTSOURCE', dirname(__DIR__,3));
```

**DBSetting.php**

namespace shared\Models;
use CodeIgniter\Model;

class DBSetting  extends Model {

```
function __construct()
{       
    parent::__construct();                  
}


public function save() {    
    return true;
}
```

}

We can also call the model in site 2. Just set the correct path in Autoload.php to refer to models in site 2.

**Note :**
If the model in site 2 content another model or link, if we call from the site 1 then codeigniter 4 system will read the link, model from site 1. So make sure  to call the plain model in site 2. Or just create a share model folder like above.

Answer (score 0):

You can access models within your classes by creating a new instance or using the model() helper function.

example like this

```
// Create a new class manually
$userModel = new \App\Models\UserModel();

// Create a new class with the model function
$userModel = model('App\Models\UserModel', false);

// Create a shared instance of the model
$userModel = model('App\Models\UserModel');
```

Comment: The problem is the model is in the site2. And I shared the system between the site1 and site 2. This is a multi application in single installation codeigniter 4. Seem your answer doesn't related to the question.

Answer (score 0):

It makes no real sense to me for different apps call each others models. If this was a HMVC structure where you had modules and they could talk to each other inside the same app, that would make sense. But since these are two different apps makes no sense because in the long run you're basically creating dependencies between them when they should work on their own.

Either way, if you really want to do that you may need to do that in a native way and not in a codeigniter way.

```
namespace App\Controllers;
require_once ROOTSOURCE . '/app/Models/UserModel.php';

class Home extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {                
        //Access the model like so:
        $setting = new UserModel();                                                    

        return view('welcome_message');
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try it ?. It is not working. I got the claas not found again

Comment: Actually the site is between main site and subdomain site. So I don't want code twice in the models.

Comment: @DennisLiu how am I supposed to try your code in your environment. if it says class not found its because the path is not correct. Check the entire path for the model you want to add. Even if its sub-domains. In the future your sub-domain can grow and you need to move it to another server keeping the main site in the current server and everything will break because you have this weird dependency.

Comment: Furthermore if you really want to do that, my advice would be to create modules and not separate applications. One module per sub-domain, one for your main site. All your sub-domains and main domain would point to the same application and that application would load the modules based on the sub-domain that was loaded. That was each module has its own namespace and the models that are supposed to be used between sites can stay in the main app. This way everything will work because you can get to any model with namespaces.

Comment: I have a correct path. But still got error class not found. Thanks for the advice.